# PHP session_id never the same on refresh

Tags: php, session

I am trying to use session_id() on some php pages, but the id changes between every file and it changes everytime i refresh the page. I placed the following script which should increment on ever reload, but it does not.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['hits'])) $_SESSION['hits'] = 0;
++$_SESSION['hits'];

echo '<p>Session hits: ', $_SESSION['hits'], '</p>';
echo '<p>Refresh the page or click <a href="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
'">here</a>.';
```

In my php.ini file, I have cookies turned on as well as set my save_path tp '/tmp'.

In the actual folder, there are session files... so i know it is not a file writing issue. I have also ensured that every file is utf-8 with bom to ensure consistency.

If there are any other solutions you can think of, please help me solve this. It is driving me insane.

Thanks!!!

Comment: How are you using session_id() exactly?

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my side, so it's most likely a PHP configuration or permission issue.

Comment: @Bilbonic have you looked at your server logs? There must be an error or warning somewhere

Comment: Actually, can you convert your files to UTF-8 **without** BOM ? The BOM may be interpreted as page content rather than PHP code, then sent to the browser even before the code has executed, and once that's done your code has no way of sending any more headers (thus no session cookie is set), it should trigger a `Headers already sent` warning but your configuration is probably set to hide warnings.

Comment: Sorry i mistyped. They are all utf-8 without BOM

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. My index was including a header file. Inside of the header, it was included several different files. The header was being referred to by path, but the files in the header file were being referred to by their absolute address. That's what was causing the different session_id()'s. There was one being created for the website with http://www. and one without. I went through and made everything refer to each other in the same format and that seemed to fix the problem. Thank you all for the replies and suggestions. Helped me track down the problem through my logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3 possibilities I can think of for your situation are:

1. How are you calling `session_id()`? Include that code in your question. If you're calling it with *any* arguments it will override the session ID to whatever argument you passed.
2. Are cookies enabled in your browser? The session ID is sent to the browser as a cookie.
3. Are you calling `session_destroy()` at any point? This will delete the session data from the server and cause a new session to be started on subsequent pageviews.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped me track down the error. Everything is working now! THANKS!

Answer (score -3):

That is because you are creating a new session every time you refresh the page. You must enclose your session start statement in a if.

`if(session_id() == ''){
   session_start();
 }`

Comment: Incorrect. `session_start()` just starts the session "engine" and allows sessions to work. It automatically creates a new session if there is none but it won't overwrite an already existing session.

Comment: @AndréDaniel how are you assuming the op has already created a session before he calls session_start() here?

Comment: @AndréDaniel that's not true. If the session hasn't been set, referencing $_SESSION should through an error. If anything, this answer is the way to check for an existing session

Comment: @AndréDaniel I'm sure he's not using only using this piece of code. Maybe he destroys the session in another script before getting to this one. It's too big of an assumption to say that it's his php configuration

Comment: @NuGnojMik either his browser rejects the session cookie, or the web server truncates/removes the `Set-Cookie` header due to a bug (already saw this on another question), or his PHP configuration is incorrect. Besides that, our "job" here is to work with the code that the author has given to reproduce the issue and not waste our time speculating about other code that may interfere with this one.

Comment: I went to double check the documentation and I believe Andre is right. If OP doesn't destroy the session then could the issue  be that php cannot physically store the session or that OP doesn't have  cookies enabled?

Comment: @Ferox it can't be because he's already said he can see the session files

Comment: @AndréDaniel I agree that it could be his browser rejecting cookies. As for the amount of code , it definitely is insufficient (as I have said in the question comments ) to make any conclusions. We can only make suggestions