# PHP session_id regenerated on refresh

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am having problems with the `session_id()` that returns a new value every time on browser refresh/restart.

Read this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25776452/php-session-id-never-the-same-on-refresh) but it doesn't solve the issue.I did all that was mentioned there - browser accepts cookies, permissions are set correctly, no param value is changed on sequential requests, etc.

Could this be refered to not using the `session_name()` or `session_set_cookie_params()` correctly? Or maybe it is the initial configuration that should be fine-tuned?

```
public static function init_session($name = FALSE, $lifetime = 10, $path = '/', $domain = FALSE, $secure = FALSE)   
{
    if (empty($name))
    {
        $name = APP_NAME;
    }

    if (empty($domain))
    {
        $domain = BASE_URL;
    }

    session_name($name);

    session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, $domain, $secure, TRUE);

    session_start();

    echo session_id();
}
```

Comment: I think you posted the wrong link, I don't see the relation to a CSS3 question.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: Comment the calls to `session_name()` and `session_set_cookie_params()` and see if it works. If it works then uncomment one of the two calls, check again and so on. When it stops working you have found the problem.

Comment: Try not to mix the data type of the variable `$name`. You initialize it as boolean and then set a string value to it. Better to use `$name = ''` in your function signature.

Comment: @Chris this should be fine. I think you need it so the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) call works correctly

Comment: Your session lifetime is set to 10 seconds, pls see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you set your **session lifetime** to **10 seconds**, which means that you get a new session after every 10 seconds.

Side note: It's normal behaviour for some browsers to discard **session cookies** when closing the browser.

If you need your session to expand over multiple browser sessions, you need to use **persistent cookies**.

Example:

```
function init_session(/* ... */)
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    //Is it a running session?
    if(isset($_SESSION['somevalue'])) {
        //Everything is fine, session is loaded, no need to reload from cookies
    } else {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['yourcookiename'])) {
            //reload session from cookie
        } else {
            create_session();
        }
    }
}

function create_session()
{
    $_SESSION['somevalue'] = 1;
    //setcookie
}
```

Read http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html

Comment: Side-fact: The browser itself does not close the session, as the browser doesn't communicate with the server when you close the page tab. The closing itself happens server-side after a timeout (so when there're no requests from the user's browser for X seconds, then the session is closed)!

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard Yes, but the session_id is changed on every request even if the interval is less. Somehow the 'time to live' is neglected.

Comment: Why less?? Try $lifetime = 100000

Comment: Or just try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#100657
As I said, not a session cookie but a persistent cookie.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard None of the methods session_name and session_set_cookie_params are working for me. When I dismiss session_name, a new session is not created (which is fine), by dismissing session_set_cookie_params the cookie is finally created on my browser. session_set_cookie_params are not working, e.g. the $lifetime is not taken in account and no cookie is created.

Comment: Can you try the same codebase in another environment? Like a portable XAMPP installation. To pinpoint the error.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard will try it, had this feeling of moving away from MAMP to LAMP.